# How can I install Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, installation

I want to switch over to Ubuntu 12.04 OS from Windows7. Where from and how can I get an installation CD of this OS, with an user manual.I do not know much about Ubuntu and I am not very tech savvy as well. My current location is Guwahati,(Assam),India.

Thanks and will remain highly obliged for the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply download it [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download). Or you can buy it [here](http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17), and they will ship it to you. But note that you won't need it(user manual), except installation. It's simpler than Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's simpler than windows and doesn't require any manual.

For me, this link was useful for downloading if you are doing it by yourself.
http://owlets.in/service-support/installation-support/